# .Net Core CLI tool not available in Visual Studio Mac

Tags: .net-core, command-line-interface, visual-studio-mac

tl;dr - custom .Net Core CLI tool not found when running as a pre-build step in Visual Studio Mac.

Full Story -

I have developed a custom .Net Core CLI tool, let's call it `ConfigTool`. This tool was developed as a .Net Core console application, and was deployed as a nuget package in a private repository.

I have a .Net Core 2.0 project that references the nuget/tool in the `csproj` as follows:

`<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="My.Namespace.ConfigTool" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>`

When building the project, it restores the nuget package, and makes the CLI tool available as `dotnet-configtool`. If I open up the terminal and navigate to my project directory and run the command `dotnet configtool` it works as expected.

Now, I want this command to run as part of the build process. So, I added the following to the bottom of my `csproj`.

`<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="dotnet configtool" />
 </Target>`

**Problem**:
When building the project from within Visual Studio Mac (Community Edition), I get the following error: `No executable found matching command "dotnet-configtool"`.

**Things tried**

1. Ran `dotnet configtool` from terminal in the project directory (windows). **Success**.
2. Ran `dotnet configtool` as a pre-build step in Visual Studio 2017 (windows). **Success**.
3. Ran `dotnet configtool` from terminal in the project directory (mac). **Success**.
4. Ran `dotnet build` from terminal in the project directory (mac). **Success**
5. Ran `dotnet configtool` as a pre-build step in Visual Studio Mac (community edition) (mac). **FAILED**.

I need this to work when running the solution from Visual Studio Mac.

Any ideas?

Comment: Report the issue to Microsoft visual Help menu.

Comment: This is a known bug https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=58925 and also reported on dev community -  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/59795/aspnet-core-bundle-minification-not-working.html

Comment: Thank you, @MattWard! Can't believe I didn't find those reports in all my searching.